# Face warp application

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to create a "face warp" application, like the one for mobile phones but for a pc desktop application instead. I have search the net for a library that does that but found none.

I want to create images like this one: http://moblog.net/view/178542/sony-ericsson-k800i-camera-phone-review-face-warp-2

Does anyone know if there is an existing library that does this, preferably in c#?
Or any image processing lib that is possible to use?

Regards Anders

Answer (score 1):

[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) may greatly help you. AFAIR, it supports face detections and some transformations.